# Cant turn ON the AWS IoT security audit through CDK

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-iot, aws-iot-device-defender

I want to enable the AWS IoT security audit through a CDK stack but it is not working.

First I followed this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty.html#interface-auditcheckconfigurationproperty) for the interface`AuditCheckConfigurationProperty`
and the following was the CDK code to enable the `IoT security audit`:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';
import { aws_iot as iot } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

export class CdkIotDeviceDefenderStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const auditCheckConfigurationProperty: iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty = {
      enabled: true,
    };

    //https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationsProperty.html
    const auditCheckConfigurationsProperty: iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationsProperty = {
        deviceCertificateExpiringCheck: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    };

  }
}
```

But the previous approach did not work. Then I followed another approach which was to use the `AWS SDK` inside the `CDK` to generate the resources in cloudformation. This is the full code:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

import { IoTClient, UpdateAccountAuditConfigurationCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-iot";

import * as sns from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns';
import * as subscriptions from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns-subscriptions';

export class CdkIotDeviceDefenderStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // SNS to receive the device defender results
    const expiredDeviceCertificateSNTopic = new sns.Topic(this, "SNSDeviceDefender", {
      displayName: 'Device Defender Expired Certificate SNS',
      fifo: false
    });

    const clientIoT = new IoTClient({ region: "us-west-2" });
    
    const auditCheckConfigParams: any = {
        roleArn: "arn:aws:iam::996242555412:role/Role_AWSIoTDeviceDefenderAudit", //Role manually created - AWSIoTDeviceDefenderAudit policy
        auditNotificationTargetConfigurations: {
            "SNS": {
                "targetArn": expiredDeviceCertificateSNTopic.topicArn,
                "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::996242555412:role/Role_AWSIoTDeviceDefenderAudit",
                "enabled": true
            }
        },
        auditCheckConfigurations: {
            "DEVICE_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRING_CHECK": {
              enabled: true,
            }
        }
    };
    (async () => {
        try {
            const iotUpdateCmd = new UpdateAccountAuditConfigurationCommand(auditCheckConfigParams);
            const iotUpdateResponse = await clientIoT.send(iotUpdateCmd);
        } catch { }
    })();

  }
}
```

Here I am creating a SNS to receive the results from device defender audit.

It did not work as well.

This is the expected result after run the CDK (The `Device Defender audit settings` enabled to true and the `Device certificate expiring` enabled to true):

[image]

But this is what I am getting in both attempts (The `Device Defender audit settings` not enabled - `IoT security audit is off`):
[image]

I am out of ideas. I don't know what I am missing.
Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my CDK stack (in python) to enable Device Defender, create audit and get notification in SNS:

```py
class DeviceDefenderStackStack(Stack):
    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        construct_id: str,
        env: Environment,
        env_params: dict,
        **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # Create IAM Role for Device Defender
        device_defender_account_audit_role = iam.Role(
            self,
            "DeviceDefenderAccountAuditRole",
            assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal("iot.amazonaws.com"),
        )

        device_defender_account_audit_role.add_managed_policy(
            iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name(
                "service-role/AWSIoTDeviceDefenderAudit"
            )
        )

        topic = sns.Topic(
            self,
            "DeviceDefenderSnsTopic",
            topic_name="device-defender-audit-topic",
            display_name="IoT Defender audit notifications",
        )

        iot_allow_sns_role = iam.Role(
            self,
            "IoTAllowSNSRole",
            assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal("iot.amazonaws.com"),
            path="/",
        )

        # Attach the policy to the IAM Role
        policy_attachment = iam.Policy(
            self,
            "SnsPolicyAttachment",
            policy_name="IotDeviceDefenderSnsPolicy",
            statements=[
                iam.PolicyStatement(
                    actions=["sns:Publish"], resources=[topic.topic_arn]
                )
            ],
        )

        iot_allow_sns_role.attach_inline_policy(policy_attachment)

        cfn_account_audit_configuration = iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration(
            self,
            "AccountAuditConfiguration",
            account_id=env.account,
            audit_check_configurations=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationsProperty(
                authenticated_cognito_role_overly_permissive_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                ca_certificate_expiring_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                ca_certificate_key_quality_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                conflicting_client_ids_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                device_certificate_expiring_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                device_certificate_key_quality_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                device_certificate_shared_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                intermediate_ca_revoked_for_active_device_certificates_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                iot_policy_overly_permissive_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                io_t_policy_potential_mis_configuration_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                iot_role_alias_allows_access_to_unused_services_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                iot_role_alias_overly_permissive_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                logging_disabled_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                revoked_ca_certificate_still_active_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                revoked_device_certificate_still_active_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
                unauthenticated_cognito_role_overly_permissive_check=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty(
                    enabled=True
                ),
            ),
            role_arn=device_defender_account_audit_role.role_arn,
            # the properties below are optional
            audit_notification_target_configurations=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditNotificationTargetConfigurationsProperty(
                sns=iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditNotificationTargetProperty(
                    enabled=True,
                    role_arn=iot_allow_sns_role.role_arn,
                    target_arn=topic.topic_arn,
                )
            ),
        )

        # Create Device Defender (DD) Audit Schedule
        dd_scheduled_audit = iot.CfnScheduledAudit(
            self,
            "DDScheduledAudit",
            scheduled_audit_name=env_params["name"]
            + env_params["device_defender"]["scheduled_audit_name"],
            frequency="DAILY",
            target_check_names=[
                "CONFLICTING_CLIENT_IDS_CHECK",
                "DEVICE_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRING_CHECK",
                "DEVICE_CERTIFICATE_KEY_QUALITY_CHECK",
                "DEVICE_CERTIFICATE_SHARED_CHECK",
                "IOT_POLICY_OVERLY_PERMISSIVE_CHECK",
                "LOGGING_DISABLED_CHECK",
                "REVOKED_DEVICE_CERTIFICATE_STILL_ACTIVE_CHECK",
                "IOT_POLICY_POTENTIAL_MISCONFIGURATION_CHECK",
                "IOT_ROLE_ALIAS_OVERLY_PERMISSIVE_CHECK",
                "IOT_ROLE_ALIAS_ALLOWS_ACCESS_TO_UNUSED_SERVICES_CHECK",
            ],
        )

        dd_scheduled_audit.add_depends_on(cfn_account_audit_configuration)
```

Comment: hi @gshpychka, thanks for your help. I did translate yor python code into typecript. When I run it cdk throws an error `"Account Audit Configuration for your account have not been set up yet"`. It seems that the `iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty - enabled: true, ` is missing but even when I use it I still get the same error. Did you have to enable the audit manually?

Comment: Do y use this in your code somewhere? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_iot/CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.html#aws_cdk.aws_iot.CfnAccountAuditConfiguration.AuditCheckConfigurationProperty